# dump all the frames in a list in android using camera2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-camera2

I'm using this [Camera2Video](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Video) implementation and recording a video. I want to extract the frames while recording the video. Can anyone suggest in which part of the code in the above given Camera2Video implementation I can get all the frames and store/dump them in a bitmap ArrayList (without losing any frames)?